# Form button not responding and badly aligned [Refactoring Ruby on Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, refactoring, frontend

I'm working on an assignment for a course I'm doing on refactoring some version of the typo blog. I need to add a new form to a page in order to get some information, the problem is that the submit button is not responding and the form is also badly alligned. https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSfp6.png

I don't have a good understanding of front-end, so this app is quite confusing for me but this is the way the page is rendered:

```
**first view that gets called:**
<% @page_heading = _('New article') %>

<%= render "admin/shared/edit", { :form_type => "article", :form_action => { :action => "new", :id => @article.id , :class => ('autosave')} } %>



**admin/shared/edit:**

<% className = form_action.delete(:class) %>
<%= form_tag(form_action, :id => "#{form_type}_form", :enctype => "multipart/form-data", :class => className) do %>

  <%= render :partial => "form" %>
<% end %>


[CODE I ADDED TO CREATE A NEW FORM]
***<h3> Merge Articles </h3>
<div class='clearfix'>
<%= form_tag(categories_path, :class => className) do %>
  <%= label :article, :merge_with, 'Article ID' %>
  <%= text_field :merge_with , '', {:class => 'span1'}%>
<% end %>
<%= submit_tag 'Merge' %>
</div>***



**_form.html.erb:**
<input type="hidden" name="current_editor" id="current_editor" value="<%= current_user.editor %>" />
<input type="hidden" name="user_textfilter" id="user_textfilter" value="<%= current_user.text_filter_name %>" />
<div id="autosave"></div>
<div id="article_keywords_auto_complete" class="auto_complete"></div>

<%= error_messages_for 'article' %>

<div class='editor-right'>
  <div class='well'>
    <h4><%= _("Publish settings") %></h4>
    <div class='actions'>
      <%= link_to_destroy_with_profiles(@article) unless @article.id.nil? or @article.state.to_s.downcase == 'draft' %>
      <span id='destroy_link'><%= link_to_destroy_draft @article %></span>
      <span id='preview_link'><%= link_to(_("Preview"), {:controller => '/articles', :action => 'preview', :id => @article.id}, {:target => 'new', :class => 'btn info'}) if @article.id %></span>
    </div>
    <div class='clearfix'>
        <%= _("Status:") %> <strong><%= @article.state.to_s.downcase %></strong> <a href="#" onclick="Element.toggle('status'); return false">Change</a>
      <ul class='inputs-list'>
        <li id='status' style='display: none;'>        
          <label for="article_published">
            <%= check_box 'article', 'published'  %>
            <%= _("Published") %>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='clearfix'>
      Comments are <strong>enabled</strong> and trackbacks are <strong>disabled</strong> <a href="#" onclick="Element.toggle('conversation'); return false">Change</a>
      <ul class='inputs-list' id='conversation' style='display: none'>
        <li>
          <label for="article_allow_pings">
            <%= check_box 'article', 'allow_pings' %>
            <%= _("Allow trackbacks") %>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="article_allow_comments">
            <%= check_box 'article', 'allow_comments' %>
            <%= _("Allow comments") %>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
      <div class='clearfix'>
      <%= _("Publish <strong>now</strong>") %> <a href="#" onclick="Element.toggle('publish'); return false">Change</a>
      <ul class='inputs-list'>
        <li id='publish' style='display: none;'>
          <%= calendar_date_select 'article', 'published_at', {:class => 'span3'} %>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='clearfix'>
      <%= _("Visibility:") %> <strong>public</strong> <a href="#" onclick="Element.toggle('visibility'); return false">Change</a>
      <ul class='inputs-list' id='visibility' style='display: none'>
        <li>
          <label for="article_password"><%= _("Password:") %>
            <%= password_field :article, :password, :class => 'span3' %>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='clearfix'>
      <%= _("Permalink:") %> <a href="#" onclick="Element.toggle('permalink'); return false">Change</a>
      <ul class='inputs-list' id='permalink' style='display: none'>
        <li>
            <%= text_field 'article', 'permalink', {:class => 'span4'} %>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='clearfix'>
      <%= _("Article filter") %>: <strong><%= @article.text_filter.description %></strong> <a href="#" onclick="Element.toggle('text_filter'); return false">Change</a>
      <ul id='text_filter' class='inputs-list' style='display: none'>
        <li>
          <select name="article[text_filter]" id="text_filter">
            <%= options_for_select text_filter_options, @article.text_filter %>
          </select>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class='actions'>
      <input id='save_draft' type="submit" value="<%= _('Save as draft') %>" name="article[draft]" class='btn info' />
      <%= save( _("Publish")) %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='well'>
    <h4><%= _("Categories") %></h4>
    <%= render 'categories' %>
  </div>
  <%= get_post_types %>
</div>

<div class='editor-left'>
  <div>
    <div>
      <%= text_field 'article', 'title', :class => 'span1', :style => ' width: 99%', :placeholder => _('Title') %>
    </div>

    <%= render('images', { :images => @images}) unless @images.empty? %>

    <div id='editor-menu'>
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li id="f" class='<%= "active" if current_user.editor == 'visual' %>'>
                <%= build_editor_link("Visual", 'insert_editor', 'fck', 'visual_editor', 'visual') %>
            </li>
            <li id="s" class='<%= "active" if current_user.editor == 'simple' %> '>
                <%= build_editor_link("HTML", 'insert_editor', 'simple', 'simple_editor', 'simple') %>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="editor">
      <div id='quicktags' style='<%= "display: none;" if current_user.editor == 'visual' %>'>
        <script type="text/javascript">edToolbar('article_body_and_extended');</script>
      </div>

      <div id ='visual_editor' <%= "style='display: none;'" if current_user.editor == 'simple'%> >
        <%= ckeditor_textarea('article', 'body_and_extended', {:class => 'large', :height => '300px', :rows => '20'}) if current_user.editor == 'visual' %>
      </div>

      <div id='simple_editor' class='input_text' <%= "style='display: none;'" if current_user.editor == 'visual'%> >
        <%= text_area('article', 'body_and_extended', {:class => 'large', :height => '300px', :rows => '20'}) if current_user.editor == 'simple' %>
        <%= render_macros(@macros) if current_user.editor == 'simple' %>
      </div>
    </div>

        <h4><%= _("Tags") %></h4>
    <div class='class'>
      <%= text_field 'article', 'keywords', {:autocomplete => 'off', :style => 'width: 100%'} %>
    </div>
    <%= auto_complete_field 'article_keywords', { :url => { :action => "auto_complete_for_article_keywords"}, :tokens => ','}%>     
  </div>

  <div class='separator'>
    <h4><%= _("Excerpt") %></h4>
    <div class=''>
      <%= text_area 'article', 'excerpt', {:height => '150', :style => 'width: 100%', :rows => '5'} %>
      <span class='help-block'><%=_("Excerpts are posts summaries that are shown on your blog homepage only but won’t appear on the post itself") %></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class=''>
    <h4><%= _("Uploads") %></h4>
    <p class='help-block'>Uploads will be displayed as attachments in your RSS feed, but won't appear in your articles.</p>
    <ul id='attachments' class='inputs-list'>
      <%= render 'admin/content/attachment', { :attachment_num => 1, :hidden => false } -%>
    </ul>
  </div>    
  </div>

</div>
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your submit tag is outside your form. Take it inside and it will work like a charm.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solves the problem of the submit button (I'm never going to convert from haml to html again ahah), but I still have the problem of the form not rendering alligned to the left as it should.

Comment: I really have to disappoint you, but you will not find an answer for every small detail. Take care of your css and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use CSS to align your form to the left. The best way to do this is going into app/assets/articles.css (or any of your CSS files) and adding this line:

```
.left { text-align: left; }
```

Then go back into your views and assign anything you want to align to the left the "left" class, for example in your form you can wrap the relevant portions in a div to make everything align left:

```
<div class="left">
  <%= form_tag(categories_path, :class => className) do %>
    <%= label :article, :merge_with, 'Article ID' %>
    <%= text_field :merge_with , '', {:class => 'span1'}%>
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Merge' %>
</div>
```